# Update a column that exist in the many to many relationship table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables which are User table, Events table, and Events_user table. I have four columns in the Events_user table which are :

```
   Schema::create('events_user', function(Blueprint $table){

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('events_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('events_id')->references('id')->on('events')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('eventstatus')->unsigned()->index();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have a function which add an event base on the user id, show one user can have many of the events. But the event can share to other user. The function is like this :

```
  public function store(EventsRequests $request){

        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $events= Events::create($request->all());
        $events->user()->attach($id); //Store the User_ID and the Event_ID at the events_user table.

        Flash::success('Your event has been created!');
        return redirect('/');//Return into home page

//        return $events;
    }
```

Then it will help me update my events_user table, but how do I update the column which is eventstatus? 
Can anyone show me how could I update it? Cause I want to use the eventstatus help me determine if there is '1' then cant be edit, then the edit button will disappear.
How many way can accomplish to the function?

---

For the show page:
I have use the function when the user click the event that exist on the calendar view, then the javascript will pass the id back and redirect to the view with the id.

```
public function show($id){
//            $user_id=Auth::user()->name;
            $showevents = Events::findOrFail($id);
            return view('events.show',compact('showevents','user'));
    }
```

How about when i want to pass the eventstatus into the view? So i can check on my view, if the eventstatus equal to one, the edit button wont show up.

---

**Updated relationship model**

**User.php**

```
   public function events(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Events');
    }
```

**Events.php**

```
   public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('eventstatus');
    }
```

Comment: always you want the eventstatus to have the value "1" ?

Comment: Ya, cause i want use 1 to determine that the event cant be edit. Show i dont want to show the edit button show my show view if the eventstatus = 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to update the field while making the association, you can pass an array of `field=>value` pairs as the second parameter to the `attach()` method. You can read in the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships).

```
$events->users()->attach($id, ['eventstatus' => 1]);
```

If you want to update the field for an existing association, you can pass an array of `field=>value` pairs to the `save()` method:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$event = $user->events()->first();
$user->events()->save($event, ['eventstatus' => 1]);
```

If you want to access the field to read the data, you can access it through the `pivot` property:

```
$user = Auth::user();
foreach ($user->events as $event) {
    echo $event->pivot->eventstatus;
}
```

In addition to all of this, you need to make sure your relationship definitions include access to the extra property:

```
// User class:
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class)->withPivot('eventstatus');
}

// Event class:
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withPivot('eventstatus');
}
```

#### Edit

*updated answer for additional question*

To get the information you're looking for, you need to be able to get to the pivot record. The pivot record is available on the models in the loaded relationship.

Since you have the Event, you need to go through the related User models, find the user you want (assuming the logged in user), and then get the status off of the pivot attribute on that user.

```
public function show($id)
{
    // get your event
    $showevents = Events::findOrFail($id);

    // get your user
    $user = Auth::user();

    // default status to send to view
    $status = 0;

    // if there is a user...
    if ($user) {
        // find the user in the "user" relationship
        // NB: calling "find" on a Collection, not a query
        $eventUser = $showevents->user->find($user->id);

        // if the user is associated to this event,
        //   get the status off the pivot table,
        //   otherwise just set the default status
        $status = $eventUser ? $eventUser->pivot->eventstatus : $status;
    }

    // add your status to the data sent to the view
    return view('events.show', compact('showevents', 'user', 'status'));
}
```

In addition to all this, make sure both relationship definitions include the `->withPivot('eventstatus')`. You want to make sure you can get at it from both sides, if need be.

Comment: This is working, @patricus but this one is for show method. How about when i want to the event with the eventstatus? I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi, @patricus, the status you set to zero is for which purpose?

Comment: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$pivot` this error will appear when i want to use the pivot.

Comment: @Ben I just assumed 0 was the opposite of your status of 1. You can set it to whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: @Ben Make sure you're calling `pivot` on a model, not the collection. In my code above, the `find()` method will return a model, so that should work. If you need further help, you would probably be better of posting a new question with the new code that is causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this method works fine, now i gonna to fix if that is zero then what should do.Thanks

Comment: @patricus: what if the field to update is in the User table?

Answer (score 3):

Can you share your event and user model relationship code?
so , it will help me to get into deep.

OR 
you can try this in event model like:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')
        ->withPivot('eventstatus')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

then while updating you can do something like this iam not sure but hope this help.

```
$events->user()->attach($id,['eventstatus' => 1]);
```

Thanks

For fetching extra column:

```
public function show($id){
        $showevents = Events::findOrFail($id);
        $event_status = $showevents->pivot->eventstatus;
        return view('events.show',compact('showevents','event_status'));
}
```

but for that you have to define this column in models:

```
// User class:
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class)->withPivot('eventstatus');
}

// Event class:
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withPivot('eventstatus');
}
```

Comment: I have update the question. YOu might look at it. After i pass the data to the view, `$event_status->eventstatus;` like this to call out the data?

Comment: No i think you just need to use $event_status. it would contains your value (1 or 0) i mean whatever...

Comment: When i try ` {{$event_status}}` in my view form, it show me the error which is trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: You can't call `pivot` on the event like that. The `pivot` attribute is on the related models, otherwise how is the code shown supposed to know what pivot record to access?